# Unable to find an album in iTunes while I see it using web browser

Tags: itunes, music, apple-music

So I'm in Australia and I bought Apple Music, I wanted to pull a particular album I really enjoy.

> Artist - **Recoil**, title - **1+2**

While I can see it in browser [by googling it](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/1-2/id827817428).

[image]

*Above screenshot is from iTunes via browser where I'm not logged in.*

**I'm unable to see it in my iTunes app on iPhone and Mac** when I search using phrases "recoil" and / or "1+2.

[image]

The last one in search results is Hydrology, while (**1+2** - the oldest LP) should appear on the very right but it does not. Is it because of some licensing issues in Australia Apple Store? What could be the issue. Could other people from different countries try to search it and check if it appears?

Answer (score 1):

Your link to the iTunes web preview points to the US store. Looks like that the album is not available in the Australian store. Some albums are region specific. That's why you could not find it in the Apple Music app on your iPhone.

Comment: I am based in Australia and can confirm that this particular song is not yet available here.